# How would I use the .split function to separate different data types into 2D arrays?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, split

I have a .txt file that has several lines like this:

`Robot 1923 human M 12M Star Gaze, 73, 1543, B, Joseph Smith`

`Sanction 1932 indigo X 23X GI, 9999, 14, R`

I have multiple 2D arrays, one for each data type. Int, char, string, and double. Each array needs to be filled with its specific data type only. I believe I should use the .split function to do this, but I have no idea how. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance, and if I wasn't clear enough I can try to help clear things up in the replies.

Answer (score 0):

The Java API documentation on [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) is a good place to start.

Assuming you know how to get a `String` from your file (represented in the sample code as `line`), you can do something like this:

```
String line = "C3PO 1977 humanoid M 11M Star Wars, 70, 1750, A, Anthony Daniels";

// As per the documentation, the split() method will return a String array, broken
// along the lines of the regular expression provided as argument

String[] values = line.split(",");

// Some variable names to hold the elements of the array

String foo;
int bar;
double baz;
String quz;
String actor;

foo = values[0];

// Converting data type... exceptions must be caught and handled

try {
    bar = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(NullPointerException e1) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    baz = Double.parseDouble(values[2]);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(NullPointerException e1) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

quz = values[3];

actor = values[4];
```

Just keep in mind that this code doesn't do much to address the quality of input. Your input file should be regular (same number of columns in each line, same data types throughout the column), otherwise the code will fail badly.

Comment: This approach would also fail if there are any random commas. For example `"Monsters, Inc."` would cause some issues

Comment: Thanks for both responses guys. I was able to pretty much figure it out with splitting and using the next() functions to pick specific words/characters/ints and just go through each part of the sentences. Then just used a loop to store each part into the 2d arrays. The text file I was given isn't too brutal and my program worked fine with it.